# To write a Query to sort in Uppercase in php my admin.

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

How to execute a query to convert a column in UPPERCASE in php myadmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

> mysql Upper() function

For reference: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-upper-function.php

Comment: You shouldn't obviously low quality questions like this. It only encourages them to continue doing it.

Comment: Sorry sir, i have researched but could not find a perfect match so i ask a question,
Anyway thank you. :)

Comment: @John If all users think like this, then how beginners will get solution? Why you are expecting all the users to be experts? Why stack overflow is not encouraging starters?